# ngModel binding to radio button in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, radio-button, dynamically-generated

I have value "n" for Non Rule Based and "R" for Rule based.
Depending this value, I need to select the Radio button value in the UI dynamically.

In ts.

```
this.vGroup = this.arr.vzGroup; // the value of vGroup is either "R" or "N"
```

I need to create a radio button in the UI with option "Rule" and "Non Rule" and option should be selected. 
Can someone help here.

This is what I tried

```
<input type="radio" name="optradio" [checked]=" *ngIf="vzGroup=='R'" ? 'true' : 'false' ">
    <input type="radio" name="optradio" [checked]=" *ngIf="vzGroup=='N'" ? 'true' : 'false' ">
```

Comment: Help is coming, on the way...

Comment: So what have you tried, show us your template where you are trying to do this...

Comment: something like this, As of now, I am printing the value in a text, but for radio button option, I tried like this..                                                                                 <input type="radio" name="optradio" [checked]=" *ngIf="vzGroup=='R'" ? 'true' : 'false' ">
 <input type="radio" name="optradio" [checked]=" *ngIf="vzGroup=='N'" ? 'true' : 'false' ">

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for-

```
<input type="radio" name="rule" [checked]="vGroup=='R'">
<input type="radio" name="rule" [checked]="vGroup=='N'">
```

Comment: @WebDev Is this what you were looking for?